# Use svn on the command line on Linux and Mac. How to bypass username and password

Tags: linux, macos, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save password when using Subversion from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899209/how-to-save-password-when-using-subversion-from-the-console)

Use svn on the command line on Linux and Mac. How to bypass username and password.

Can someone please tell me if I can setup svn somehow on linux and the mac to stop asking for the username and password...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common way is to use svn+ssh by registering your public ssh key at the remote repository.  You can then use ssh-agent to remain 'authenticated locally' and the ssh protocol takes care of the rest.

Several of the repositories have HOWTOs on ssh use, see e.g. [here for Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SSH%20keys).