# Why every time execute svn command need type password explicitly

Tags: svn

Right now find a problem of svn, ubuntu system(`Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`), execute svn command in terminal every time need to enter password explicitly. See below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install subversion
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)
   compiled Aug 20 2015, 12:51:30 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
svn checkout https://svn.foo.com/svn/server/bar
cd bar
$ svn log|head
Authentication realm: <https://svn.foo.com:443> VisualSVN Server
Password for 'foo':
```

why every time need I to  type password? How could I store it ? And [official doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds) do not tell how to store password explicitly, so it seems svn default store password.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer here: [How to save password when using Subversion from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899209/how-to-save-password-when-using-subversion-from-the-console)

Comment: I just join a new company, and here uses svn.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved above problem by below work

```
# foo is my current login username
which svn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 foo foo 266528  8月 20 21:19 /usr/bin/svn
rm -rf .subversion
svn checkout https://svn.foo.com/svn/server/bar
cd bar
# do not need input password now
svn log|head
```

As for real reason why before can not store password I' m not clear. Maybe   due to this
[image]