# git svn clone --password pass gives “Unknown option: password”

Tags: svn, passwords, git-svn

I want to clone a svn repository using git, with a username and password given on the command-line.

I can write:

```
svn checkout --username user --password pass svn://server/repo
```

But I can't use `--password` with `git svn clone`:

```
git svn clone --username user --password pass svn://server/repo
Unknown option: password
```

**How can I give the password to `git svn clone` on the command-line?**

**Alternatively, is there a kind of `--svn-options` switch to git-svn?**

P.-S. Note that I need to specify it on the command-line, because there are multiple repos on this server with different user/pass, and svn stupidly assumes that all repos use the same username/password, so half of the time I get `svn: Authorization failed`, without it asking for the password, even if I use `--username` (it seems to ask for the password sometimes, but it's not robust enough to be used in a script).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15771437/6309 could help

Comment: @VonC yes, I had already read that, but none of the solutions are acceptable, as the answer says.

Answer (score 21):

`git svn` uses SVN commands directly and thus the internally saved password of SVN.

Run the command:

```
svn checkout --username user --password pass svn://server/repo
```

and let SVN remember your password.

If this does not work remove the saved SVN authentications:

```
$HOME/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/*
```

Then `git svn clone` will prompt you for the password.

Comment: Just a note. svn checkout can be quite time consuming. There is no need to wait for it to complete though. Once the checkout starts, the password is saved and you can cancel the checkout process (Ctrl+C is windows).

Comment: try `--depth empty` as in `svn checkout --username someuser --password somepass --depth empty <svn-url>`

Comment: If you're just running it to get the password reset, you can just do `svn log` instead of `svn checkout`. That will probably complete so quickly that it won't be worth your time to try to ctrl+c it.

Comment: This answer explains the managing of the svn password but is not a solution regarding the question.

Answer (score 15):

Just specify the username with `--username` and you should be prompted for a password.

See `git svn --help` or `man git svn` for further information.

Comment: As noted in my question, I needed to give the password on the command-line, not be prompted for it (unless I can safely pipe an "echo" into that or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the password (in batch processing) to `git svn ...` as described here: https://superuser.com/a/542256/1047499.